# Чтение и запись в контейнер без блокировки в многопоточном приложении

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Один поток записывает пары {key, value} в контейнер. Другой поток читает только первые N пар {key, value} из этого контейнера. Как это можно реализовать без блокировки? Вопрос с собеседования по C++

Comment: А вообще, тут напрашивается кольцевой буфер, коих реализаций существует довольно много. Да и свой при желании можно легко придумать.

Comment: мне кажется обычная очередь - с одного конца впихиваем, с другого вынимаем ) Первый поток все время добавляет данные, второй ждет (получая сообщения от очереди об изменении размера) пока длина очереди станет больше N, после чего считывает (вынимает) данные.

Comment: если реализовывать на базе std::list - то легко может получиться.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin боюсь тогда вы все равно словите UB) Потому что может так сложиться, что память в контейнере под N-ый элемент уже выделена, но он еще не построен и не существует, например. Тогда вы рискуете прочитать в лучшем случае мусор из памяти. Если я не прав, то поправьте)

Comment: @ComeInRage резонно,  тогда пусть будет N+1

Comment: @AlexanderChernin а это уже костыли))) Но работать будет, наверное. За исключением тех случаев, когда какой-нибудь объект посередине контейнера решит самовыпилиться и вызовется его деструктор. Тогда мы рискуем прочитать не до конца удаленный объект, что тоже приведет к UB. Честно говоря, я даже не представляю, как это можно реализовать без блокировок

Comment: Возможно сделать переменную-флаг, сигнализирующую о том, что N объектов уже построены и готовы быть считанными. Но это - прямой путь к ошибкам

Comment: Что есть "первые N пар"? Если это какой-то `map`, то вполне можно записать/добавить пару, которая вдруг станет "первой", т.к. отсортировано по ключам. В общем, требуется уточнение.

Comment: @ComeInRage на самом деле хватит и N, если очередь/список будет сам сигнализировать своим слушателям об изменении своего состояния (количестве элементов) уже после завершения очередной операции.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin да, я об этом и сказал. Но на практике такое лучше не делать, чревато выстрелами в ногу. Странный вопрос у работодателя, однако)